# How to write poststring to API swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm new here. How to write and turn the code below into postString as I need to do submisson to API.

```
{
    "service": 0,
    "size": "string",
    "orderReference": "string",
    "dropOffHubId": "string",
    "pickUpHubId": "string",
    "courierId": "string",
    "from": {
        "address": {
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "city": "string",
            "postcode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "country": "string"
        }
    },
    "to": {
        "name": "string",
        "phone": "string",
        "email": "string",
        "address": {
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "city": "string",
            "postcode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "country": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I correct if I write it in this way, but how to put in the string after  **"from": {** and also **"address": {** then go into **"address1": "string"**, Then another one is **"to": {** **"name": "string"**, then go inside 
**"address": {**, then go inside **"address1": "string"**,

```
let postString = [ "service": 0,
                   "size": "string",
                   "orderReference": "string",
                   "dropOffHubId": "string",
                   "pickUpHubId": "string",
                   "courierId": "string",
                   "from": "fromAddArr",
                   "to": "toAddArr"] as [String : Any]
var request = URLRequest(url:URL!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(bearerToken!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options:.prettyPrinted)
```

I only know to write in this way.

```
{
  "refNo": "string",
  "code": "string"
}

let postString = ["refNo": "string",
                          "code": "string"]
```

Comment: Change `"from": "fromAddArr",    "to": "toAddArr"` With `"from": fromAddArr,   "to": toAddArr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one i think you want something like this** : First  take dictionary of address from current json and convert that dictionary into string  :

```
let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["address": [
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "city": "string",
            "postcode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "country": "string"
        ]
    ]

    if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: dictionary, options: []) {
        let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .utf8)
        print("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)") //you can use this string to create dictionary as you want 
        let dict = ["addres":theJSONText!]
        print(dict)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write that string by yourself. If you are using swift 3 and have a model class for that JSON string, you can use a third party lib [here](https://github.com/mukeshydv/JSONParserSwift). This will convert your model into dictionary, array, json string and data etc. You just need to make your model child of `ParsableModel` or `JSONParsable`.

If you have problem in creating model class from JSON you can use [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yi32SFTY7UzdTQ_W-FWBmd-2yn_HTnsc/view?usp=sharing) utility. This will generate model class for your JSON:

```
class RootClass {
    var courierId: String?
    var dropOffHubId: String?
    var from: From?
    var orderReference: String?
    var pickUpHubId: String?
    var service: NSNumber?
    var size: String?
    var to: To?  
}

class To {
    var address: Addres?
    var email: String?
    var name: String?
    var phone: String? 
}

class From {
    var address: Addres?  
}

class Addres {
    var address1: String?
    var address2: String?
    var city: String?
    var country: String?
    var postcode: String?
    var state: String?
}
```

If you are using Swift 4. It provides you classes to Encode and Decode your code from JSON to model and model to JSON. You can save your time by using this.